# How to create own controller method with OutOfMemory or Stack Overflow Error

Tags: java, model-view-controller, controller, token, stack-overflow

I have Java Web Application (WAR), deployed on google app engine. I want to create some controller method, that will take some hardcode token(or user:password) and do some recursion, to kill my application. I was thinking something about this

```
@Controller
public class Controller {

@RequestMapping(value="/killApp, method=REQUESTMETHOD.GET)
public String killApp(@Request param String token)

String token = "hardcoded token"

Some recursion method, that will call Stack Over Flow Error
}
return
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Go ahead.... A recursion without end, and that will do

Comment: You would be crazy to deploy such code to your production environment, as it is a super-cheap way for someone to DOS your service. You would absolutely want to make sure that the implementation is conditional on NOT being used in production.

Comment: Thanks, I know about it, but I want to try to investigate how it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made something like this

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/kill/{killCode}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void killAll(@PathVariable String killCode) {
        if (Objects.equals(killCode, "lsjfkldsjf56564k"))
        killAll(killCode);
    }

}
```

Now, when I want to kill application, I'm just picking this into address bar and press OK, it gives me Stack Over Flow Error